# Language neutral entry pages

Tags: php, url, localization

My old web site has an `index.html` page … nothing strange! Everything is fine.

The new web site has an english and a french version, so the new index is `index.php?lang=eng…`. That makes sense.

I don’t like to make a front page that will say “english” or “french”. But that’s not good for ranking or seo.

So the question is: How do I manage to get a default `index.php` with request (`?lang=eng`) to become the front page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you think about that solution

```
<?php
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    if ( empty($lang) ) $lang = 'fra';
    header( 'Location: http://acecrodeo.com/new/01-acec.php?lang='.$lang) ;
?>
```

Comment: That's good, but it will throw either a notice or warning if $_GET['lang'] is not set.  Better to assign $lang FROM $_GET only if $_GET['lang'] is not empty.

Answer (score 3):

- domain.com/en/index.php
- domain.com/fr/index.php

Use url rewriting with regular expressions (mod_rewrite, ISAPI, whatever) to handle requests to relevant pages so

- domain.com/en/index.php REWRITE TO domain.com/index.php?lang=en
- domain.com/fr/index.php REWRITE TO domain.com/index.php?lang=fr

This way your pages are two seperate pages to search engines but handled via one gateway in code. I'm not a regex expert but it would be a very simple regex I would imagine

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the question.  It seems to have two parts:

How to provide a default language of English:

`$lang = empty($_GET['lang']) ? "eng" : $_GET['lang'];`

Do you also have a problem of where to put the English/Francais links so search engines don't ding you?  I wasn't aware of this problem.

It might also help to let us know if you're using a CMS, and if so which one.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, in index.php, when you check the language, put something like this:

```
$lang = @$_GET['lang'];
if ( empty($lang) ) $lang = 'eng';
```

Comment: Would cause an error if $_GET['lang'] is not set. Exchange the assignments and it’s fine.

Comment: I must have something funny on my server, as I've never gotten an error from accessing an invalid GET parameter (just a null value back).  Still, I'll add a @ just in case

Comment: normally I'd say @ is evil, but in this case it's just what we want :)

Comment: sine i dont get any error, and cannot get ANY information on the net searching for "@$_GET".. i will not add it...

Comment: FYI - Putting the "@" before a statement just means "ignore any errors that may be generated by this"

Answer (score 1):

Just put an argument in the php code that says :

```
if (lang == "")  // haven't done php in a while so the syntax is probably wrong
{
  lang = "eng";
}
```

In other words, if there isn't an argument on the lang variable, you can just set it to be eng automatically, and so the first page will default to English every time, unless told otherwise.

Comment: Code should be more $lang=fetchLangFromQueryString();if($lang == "") $lang = "eng";, don't quite the remember the correct syntax myself either though...

Comment: Top guy got the syntax right.
Like I said, it's been a while, we get banned from using php at Uni.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the default english and offer an option on the index page to change to french? This, of course, depends on what language most of the visitors speak, which isn't all that hard to figure out with visitor logs.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a neutral URL for entry, such as:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar
```

On this page I would do some [language negotiation](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-when-lang-neg) or simply ask the user for the prefered language. Then I can redirect to the language specific URL:

```
http://example.com/en/foo/bar
```